# Override Ansible default pacakge manager

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Prior to Ansible 2.5 I was able to set override the default package manager used by Ansible's `package` module to use a different Ansible module. In a playbook like this looked like:

```
tasks:
  - set_fact:                                                                                                                                                                                        
      ansible_pkg_mgr: pacaur
```

After upgrading to Ansible 2.5.3 setting the above no longer changes the package manager and `package` still tries to use the `pacman` module, the default for my OS. Any suggestions for overriding the package manager fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the package module, you could use the `use` directive to specify which package manager you want to use. For example

```
- package:
    name: spotify
    use: pacaur
```

It is not recommended to override facts gathered by ansible, as it would lead to unexpected behaviour.

To answer your question:

From what I see this should not work, as ansible is doing a lookup to see if the specified module in the `use directive` (apt/yum/pacman) or the value from `ansible_pkg_mgr` exists or not.

`package` is an action plugin which returns the os package manager based on the distribution / operating system and it requires the package manager to be implemented as an Ansible module. The implementation of the package plugin has been slightly changed between version 2.4 abd 2.5. You can refer to the code [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/7ffbdd52145e86b6194b0040ef7ff6c529ebad62/lib/ansible/plugins/action/package.py#L43). If the module is not available ansible would fail immediately.

***Update***

So, the reason why the override is not working anymore is because, with the 2.5 release all ansible facts were moved to `ansible_facts.*` namespace. The `ansible_*` namespace is still available but will be deprecated in a future release.

When you look at the file linked above, you notice the following change

In version 2.4

```
module = self._templar.template('{{ansible_pkg_mgr}}')
```

and in 2.5

```
module = self._templar.template('{{ansible_facts.pkg_mgr}}')
```

So, in version 2.5 the package plugin is getting the value of the fact (pkg_mgr) from `ansible_facts.pkg_mgr` so you need to set that fact to pacaur and not `ansible_pkg_mgr`. So your set fact, should be as below and your playbook would work as before.

```
- set_fact:
    ansible_facts:
      pkg_mgr: pacaur
```

Comment: This is for a personal project using ansible to set up my development environment, so I'm not worried about unexpected behavior from overriding the package manager in the entire project. I understand I can pass the `use` flag to each `package` invocation, but I'd really rather change the default as it will cut down on a lot of repetitive code. Overriding the `ansible_pkg_mgr` fact used to work, and I'd like to find an alternative that continues to

Comment: I am surprised that it worked for you, when you overrode the ansible_pkg_mgr fact. It wont work when you set it to pacaur because there is no module named pacaur implemented by ansible. Unless you are shipping a pacaur module along with your role.

Comment: Yeah I install an ansible module that provides the `pacaur` directive

Comment: @Michael I have updated the answer with the reasoning and it should work

Comment: Sorry for the delay, your updated answer works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Can you update the answer with which file the `-package` data should be in?

Comment: @user239558 For example, it could be in tasks/main.yaml . But it should be set before using the package module to install packages